# How to use {user-id}/friends endpoint to get all friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a url that returns the first 330 (the maximum limit) friends of a user that looks like this:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/friends?fields=first_name,last_name&limit=330&offset=0&access_token={access-token}`

And that returns a structure like:

```
{
  "data": [...], // length of 330
  "paging": {
    "next": ...
  }
}
```

With `paging.next` looking like:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/friends?fields=first_name,last_name&limit=330&offset=330&access_token={access-token}&__after_id=100005110960070`

The problem comes here. **When I use this url, the `data` array is empty, even though the user has more than 330 friends**. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: this might help. read this? https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Comment: _“the first 330 (the maximum limit)”_ – 330 is such an arbitrary number, I don’t think that is actually the maximum limit one can use. I think the problem might rather be that you did not take into account that not all friends are _visible_ to apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem before.

**Limit&Offset** parameters in Facebook Graph API does not work right completely.
See here : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

So, in your case, to fetch all friends, don't specify the limit&offset parameters in the url.
For example :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{user-id}/friends?fields=first_name,last_name.
```

Then, use **paging.next** to fetch the next data until **paging.next** return an empty array.

I've test an account which has more than **4.200 friends**. It worked fine without need to using **paging.next.**

Comment: Facebook needs to put that in big, bold letters as not to confuse people. Thanks for the help.